# tolua and template methods

Tags: c++, binding, lua

I need to bind a simple template method to LUA, something like

```
void addComponent<T>(IComponent*);
```

I'm using tolua to do the bindings but it doesn't support class/method templates (tolua++ supports class templates but not the method ones :) ). Is there any way to bind this method manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide examples of how you want to use this method?

Comment: Something like this from lua: `go=GameObject:new();  animComponent=AnimComponent:new();  go:addComponent(animComponent);`    Sorry, Have tried to format the comment using mini-Markdown formatting but don't know why it is not doing it. Hope it is more or less clear.

Comment: For the next one, know that you can just edit your original question and add any relative code asked there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ templates do not actually exist outside of the compiler. *Instantiations* of templates exist, but the templates themselves are purely a compile-time construct.

There is no function called `void addComponent<T>(IComponent*);` There *is* a function called, `void addComponent<int>(IComponent*)` or `void addComponent<float>(IComponent*)` or for any particular type you want. But templates are not real functions.

You can bind an *instantiation* of a template, which is a concrete function. This works just like binding any free function in toLua. The name of an instantiation would be, `addComponent<TypeName>` where `TypeName` is the name of the concrete type you want to instantiate it with.

To put it another way, you can't bind the concept of `addComponent` which is defined for any type. You *can* bind any actual `addComponent` that is defined for a *specific* type.

Comment: Good point. I was so concentrated on the bindings that forgot such a basic concept. In the other hand, how does luabind, etc... detect all template methods instantiations for a template method? Don't get it. I guess it does it parsing the headers but not sure.

Comment: @Notbad: Luabind doesn't allow it either; you must use concrete functions and types, not function. Luabind allows you to bind a `vector<int>` or a `vector<SomeType>`, but not a `vector`.